# Procotols supported over GRE by linux kernel

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, tunneling

Does linux kernel support L2 over GRE ?
I tried to find through the source code. I could find only ip_gre.c which supports IP over GRE.

So is there any restriction in kernel to support L2 protocols over GRE?

Thanks,
Paul